# jQuery animate from CSS "top" to "bottom"

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I'm looking to animate a div element from an absolute top position to an absolute bottom position on the page load.

The combination of CSS and jQuery code below fails to move anything:

CSS

```
#line-three {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:0px;
    top:113px;
}
```

jQuery

```
 $("#line-three").animate({
    bottom: "100px",
    }, 1200);
```

Thank you for your help!

EDIT:

I've tried changing it to this (as per graphicdevine's suggestions) but still no cigar:

```
var footerOffsetTop = $('#line-three').offset().bottom;
  $('#line-three').css({position:'absolute',top:'',bottom:footerOffsetTop})
  $("#line-three").delay(100).animate({
    bottom: '100px',
    }, 1200);
```

Comment: ok, got the code. Sorry wasn't there earlier, but had to split.

Comment: Yes, that scripted worked for FF, but didn't test in IE. I created another that doesn't use jquery ui, but had to do some tweaking to make it work.

Comment: offset().bottom doesn't exist, offset() just returns top and left properties.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I eventually came up with a solution...

Basically you animate from the old `top` position to another position also relative to to the `top` which you calculate by taking the `window` height and subtracting (1) the desired position from the `bottom`, and (2) the height of the element you want to animate. Then, at the end of the animation add a callback to change the css so as the element is then position with a bottom value and a top `auto` value

Here's the jQuery script:

```
$('#click').click(function () {

    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var lineHeight = $('#line').height();
    var desiredBottom = 100;

    var newPosition = windowHeight - (lineHeight + desiredBottom);

    $('#line').animate({top:newPosition},1000,function () {
        $('#line').css({
            bottom: desiredBottom,
            top: 'auto'
        });
    });

});
```

[You can see it working in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxkuS/176/)

Answer (score 5):

You can set top:auto with .css method and then animate:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#line-three").css({top:'auto'});   
   $("#line-three").animate({bottom:'100px'}, 200)   
})
```

EDIT:

You can play with size of body/screen and convert top position to bottom position and then animate to the desired bottom position:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var bodyHeight = $('body').height();
  var footerOffsetTop = $('#line-three').offset().top;
  var topToBottom = bodyHeight -footerOffsetTop;

  $('#line-three').css({top:'auto',bottom:topToBottom});
  $("#line-three").delay(100).animate({
    bottom: '100px',
  }, 1200);
```

})

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/reWwx/4/

Comment: But this then snaps it to the bottom and animates it up from there. I'm looking for it to move from the top down to the bottom...

Comment: From the top to the bottom of the screen? Or with respect the relative element that contains it?

Comment: That's really clever, thank you. The only problem is that I don't think that the animation will begin at the same starting point (ie, 113px) if the browser size changes...

Comment: Mmmm, you could try to set % values instead of px. Something like top: 5%

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this would help?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var div = jQuery("#dvVertigo");

    div.animate({
           left: '0',    
                top: '+=' + ($(window).height()-20)               
            }, 5000, function () {
                // Animation complete.
            });
});
```

Full code:

http://jsfiddle.net/yyankowski/jMjdR/

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: had to leave quickly so didn't get to finish, I decided to use jquery ui for the example (you need core):

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<style>
#line_three { width:100%; }
.line3_top {
    position:absolute;
    top:113px;
    left:0px;
}
.line3_btm {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100px;
    left:0px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var topbtm = true;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#line_three").mouseenter(function(){
            if ( topbtm ) {
                $("#line_three").switchClass("line3_top","line3_btm",400);
            } else {
                $("#line_three").switchClass("line3_btm","line3_top",400);
            }
            topbtm = !topbtm;
        });
    });
</script>
</head><body>
<div id="line_three" class="line3_top">
    hello;
</div>
</body></html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/syVzK/1/ (changed toggle switch to prevent over animation)

I like some other suggestions as well.

EDIT2: Just tested in IE... it works oddly. Maybe have to do straight because of odd behavior in IE with Jquery UI switch class.

**EDIT3**:

Ok, I got this working for IE and FF... Some notes though. The +20 is to keep it from jumping. The test for innerHeight of 0 is in case height isn't set for the element (or body), so if it's in an div that's positioned, then set height.

Also, this **did not work in jsfiddle**, but worked on a regular webpage. Avoid, jsfiddle for this.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var topbtm = 1,top3=113,btm3=100;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#line_three").mouseenter(function(){
        var ih = $(this).offsetParent().innerHeight();
        if (ih==0){ih=$(document).innerHeight();}
        if ( topbtm==1 ) {
            topbtm=-1;
            $("#line_three")
                .animate({"top":(ih-(btm3+20))}
                         ,500
                         ,function(){
                             $(this).css({"top":"auto","bottom":btm3});
                })
            topbtm=0;
        } else if ( topbtm==0 ) {
            topbtm=-1;
            $("#line_three")
                .animate({"bottom":(ih-(top3+20))}
                         ,500
                         ,function(){
                             $(this).css({"bottom":"auto","top":top3});
                })
            topbtm=1;
        }
    });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: This doesn't produce an animation, just a jump.

Comment: @negatron I got it working (edit3) in ie and ff, but couldn't get offsetParent() to work in jsfiddle, so it has to be tested without it. Not sure what's throwing it off, but unwilling to track that down at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#line-three").css({position:'absolute',top:'auto',bottom:'100px'})`

That should do it. You probably need to reser the 'top' value to auto

**EDIT**

To animate, you need to use .animate();

Try this:

`$("#line-three").animate({position:'absolute',top:'auto',bottom:'100px'}, 400)`

Comment: That almost does it, but rather than creating an animated slide-down it just jumps suddenly to the bottom...

Comment: Your edit is now equivalent to graphicdevine's answer (above). And that doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly:

```
 $("#line-three").animate({position:'absolute',top:'auto',bottom:'100px'},1200)
```

EDIT

Yes, this is going to be trickier than it first appears.  You'll might need to analyse it's current position relative to it's container (using `offset`) and work from there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into it. Any obvious suggestions about how to begin using offset?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate you should do:

```
$("#line-three").animate({
    top: "500px",
    }, 1200);
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/xhHrh/

Answer (score 0):

You can animate it using this:
[Check out this JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/BQ5XA/)

```
$('#button').click(function(e){ // On click of something
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default click aciton
    $("#line-three").animate({
        top: "300px",
    }, 1200);
});
```

Comment: But this doesn't position is relative to the bottom of the page no?

Comment: This will animate the div 300px from its absolute position, where ever that is. So in this case, 300px from the top of the page. So if you wanted to move it down 100px, you would move it down 113px + 100px, sorry my bad, i understand what you want to do now.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the current bottom value via: css('bottom'). This works for me (jQuery1.7.2):

```
$('#line-three').css({bottom:$('#line-three').css('bottom'), top:'auto'});
$('#line-three').animate({ bottom: position }, 250);
```