# JQuery slide up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm currently working on a website, and I got a navigation bar, which I placed at the bottom of the page, I want to make it so that when I click on one of my buttons, the navigation bar slides up to the top of my page, and when i click on that same button again, it goes back to its original position (bottom of the page).

Ive already got this piece of code written in JQuery to make my navigation bar slide up:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav-top').click(function () {
        $('#navigation').animate({ "top": "0" }, 500);
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="navigation">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#index"><span class="color">B</span>AICA</a>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-top">About me</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-top">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-top">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#navigation {
    background-image: url('../images/header/navigation/bl-opacity50.png');
    *background-image: url(../images/header/navigation/bl-opacity50.png); 
    background-repeat: repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Do i have to write some kind of IF statement?

EDIT:

It all worked out fine, but when I try to make a second button, for making my navigation bar move back to the bottom of my page, its not doing anything, so what i want is a button for moving the navigation bar to the top of the page, and a button for moving it to the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 3):

Use `.toggleClass` and keep the positioning in the CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/WkFP2/

Comment: Thanks man, but how would i animate this so it would slowly move up and down?

Comment: You would need to use the jQuery UI toggleClass which does the animation: http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/

Comment: --EDIT-- Doesn't work in this case because of the difference between top and bottom. This might be of a little more help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518400/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have to write an if statement in your jquery code. The reason is , your jquery code will work only for the first time, where it moves the div from bottom to div. When you click it again, it will still make the element to move to top only. So you need an if statement which calculates the current position of your div and move it to either top or bottom.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.nav-top').click(function () {
    if($('#navigation').position.top()!=0)
       $('#navigation').animate({ "top": "0" }, 500);
    else
       $('#navigation').animate({ "bottom": "0" }, 500);
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a css transition with a `.toggleClass` if you can set the height in the `#navigation.top` styling (using 85% as an example).

```
#navigation.top {
  top: 85%;
}
```

The transitions

```
#navigation {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

Here's a fiddle (forked from a previous answer).

http://jsfiddle.net/CmbPJ/