# How to animate a position of a fixed element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a div whose position properties is:

```
.some
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```

I then want to animate its `bottom` (not with `top`, with `bottom` property)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                  $("a").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
                      $("div").animate({ top: "none", bottom : 25});    
        });
});
```

But it does not work. The problem is that `top` property is in the priority. If I set the top to 0 then it sticks to the top, it does not care any to bottom value. However I remove the top property and animate bottom, it starts the animation right from the very bottom. I want the animation to start from the position which is designated by top value and end in where it is specified by bottom value. What should I do?

Here is the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mostafatalebi2/ex1b69g9/

Comment: Check out this post for a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518400/jquery-animate-from-css-top-to-bottom

Comment: try to change top from 0 to top 100% - 25px > top:calc(100% - 25px);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should animate from `top: 0` to `top: 100%` using a negative `margin-top` value to maintain the `div` at a certain distance from the bottom of the page. Doing so, **your `div` will move from the very top to the bottom of the page**, like you want.

To move your div exactly `25 pixels` distant from the bottom you can **set `margin-top` to the negative value of your div's height minus `25px`**.

Here's an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $div = $('div.some');
        $div.animate({
            top: '100%',
            marginTop: - $div.height() - 25
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.some {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='some'>I am a DIV!</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href='#'>Click Here!</a>
```

Comment: Would it be better if margin-top was negative the jquery calculated height of the element? and then minus another 25 pixels(so that its 25 pixels off the bottom as he originally requested)?

Comment: @joncampbell You're right, I was adding it; now the solution is better.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                  $("a").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
                      $("div").animate({ top:'500px'});    
        });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gcsx1exj/1/

Comment: This will just move the div 500 pixels down from the top, not at the bottom of the page.